# ElasticSearch Date Range Query

Tags: elasticsearch

How Can I Write 4 Elastic Search Query That Get me This Results

date in range now and 1 Hour ago

date in range now and 12 Hour Ago

date in range now and 1 Week Ago

date in range now and 1 Month ago

my date format is "date": "2018-01-07T14:33:00"

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
{
    'query': {
        'range': {
             'timestamp': {
                 'gte': 'now-1d'
             }
        }
    }
}
```

While `1d` means 1 day, and can be easily changed to `4h` or `1m` for example.

Comment: my format date like this
"date": "2018-01-07T14:33:00"
what can i do ?